# How to efficiently remove duplicates from a large table in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite, sqlite3-python

I have a table consisting of ~200 million rows and 6 columns, for which I only want to keep rows that are unique across all columns.

I am currently doing a CREATE TABLE temp AS SELECT DISTINCT * FROM plates;

This has run for 10 hours and is still running so I must be doing something wrong.  I read about indexing and grouping by rowid's, but I do not understand how this would speed up the process since it is still evaluating every row and every column. I am mainly looking for insight here, since I am probably missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
create table temp (
    a,b,c,d,e,f,
    primary key (a,b,c,d,e,f) on conflict ignore
);

insert into temp (a,b,c,d,e,f)
    select a,b,c,d,e,f from plates;
```

where `a`,`b`,`c`,`d`,`e`,`f` are the relevant columns.

Comment: possibly `unique` instead of `primary key` if nulls are allowed

Comment: Oh wow, I can just use "on conflict ignore" when inserting into the database in the first place. This changes everything :) Thank you!